# Load ckeditor in ajax content

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor to change my textareas into a wysiwyg. It all works fine, except when i load content through an Ajax call. Then my CKEditor doesn't load.

I've searched for a solution, but couldn't find any that worked for me.

My Ajax call basically looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
      success: function(data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
            $('.ckeditor').ckeditor();
      }
});
```

As you can see i tried to use the function **ckeditor()** to programmatically load the CKEditor. But this gives me the following error:

FireFox says:

> $(".ckeditor").ckeditor is not a function

And IE says:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'ckeditor'

Is there any other way to load the CKEditor by class name when the content is loaded through an Ajax call??

Comment: if the error message is '.ckeditor is not a function', then it means the js file for ckeditor was not loaded before. did you use `$(document).ready` or did you place your js snippet without the document-ready callback function at the very end of the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a way around to this. load your ckeditor as usual, but keep it hidden. and when contents are loaded through ajax populate the editor div and display through jquery.

Answer (score 7):

First you have to load the jquery adapter '/path/to/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js'

Than `$('.ckeditor').ckeditor();` will work.

Answer (score 4):

you can use command:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
```

but with one difference - editor1 is the id of the textarea and not the class.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: not for multiple ck editors if we dont want to make ids same.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the accepted answer by calling 
    `$('.ckeditor').ckeditor();`
in my ajax's success propery. Yet this gave an error.

StanleyD's answer however did work.

After appending your content with ajax, try adding the following code within the ajax's success property: 
    `CKEDITOR.replace('textareaId');`

Answer (score 1):

Had a simlar issue. I needed multiple areas with CKEDITOR after AJAX + appending elements to the page (those with editable properties). Spent a ton of hours to no avail and then...

I found this and added it AFTER setting contenteditable to true in those elements:

`CKEDITOR.inlineAll();`

Handled initializing all my CKEDITOR areas AFTER AJAX + append to page.

https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-inline

Answer (score 0):

You can use `done()` and `then()` methods after ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url
}).done(function(data){
     $('#content').html(data);
}).then(function(){
     $('.ckeditor').ckeditor();
});
```